# Show a message to the user other than window.alert

Tags: php

After the insertion, the code is submitted in the database i want to show user that he has been success in inserting the values.After that it should redirect to the page.

For redirection i used

> header("location:header.php");

I want the remaining thing to be done.I have shown a alert message using window.alert. I want other than this.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` won't give you an array with field names as keys. You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: @SimonGermain - yes it will. By default it fetches both named and numbered elements. You're thinking of `mysql_fetch_row()` which only gets the numbered elements.

Comment: @SimonGermain with `mysql_fetch_array()` you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.

Comment: That probably changed over the years. Back in the day where I had to use the mysql_ function sets (php3 and early php4), fetch_array was returning numbered elements. :)

Comment: Important Note: The `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered obsolete. The PHP developers are in the process of deprecating them, and **strongly** recommend not using them any more. You should change your code to use the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` functions instead (or use the PDO library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function to truncate the string

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I've used for a similar situation. Specify a number of characters to trim it down to. If it's shorter than that number it does nothing, but if it's longer, it'll `substr` it and pop the last bit off, replacing it with a `...`

```
function desc_trim($input, $cut = 65)
    {
        if (strlen($input) > $cut)
            {
                $input = substr($input, 0, $cut);
                $input = explode(" ", $input);
                array_pop($input);
                $input = implode(" ", $input);
                $input .= "...";
            }
        return $input;
    }
```